# Javascript if statement Google Tools

Tags: javascript

I have this button which when clicked takes the value from a input area.

If that value is 0, then it enables Google Tools and changes the value of that input text area to 1.

If that value is 1, then it disables Google Tools and changes the value of that input text area to 0.

The value of that input area is getting changed but once the Google Tools gets enabled, it doesn't get disabled if I click that button again.

And the name of that Input area is "hinditext"

Here's the code.

```js
var HindiButton = function (context) {
    var ui = $.summernote.ui;
    var button = ui.button({
        contents: '<i class="fa fa-child"/> Hindi',
        tooltip: 'Hindi',
        click: function () { 
            var x = $('#hinditext').val();
            if(x === ("0")) {
                var options = {  
                    sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,  
                    destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],  
                    shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',  
                    transliterationEnabled: true  
                };    
                var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);  
                control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);    
                $('#hinditext').val("1");
            } else if(x === ("1")) {
                var options = {  
                    sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,  
                    destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],  
                    shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',  
                    transliterationEnabled: false 
                };    
                var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);  
                control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']); 
                $('#hinditext').val("0");
            }
        }
    });

    return button.render();
}
```

Comment: You may want to make it more clear that your question is "it doesn't get disabled if I click that button again.", is really hard to find that in the code

Comment: Indenting code could help.

Answer (score 0):

As per docs https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started

transliterationEnabled is an optional field specifying whether to enable transliteration by default. If you wish to enable transliteration by default, specify this field with a value of true. The default value is false.

I think you have to either use jquery of a css to disable the input field, this parameter will not help you in disabling the field.
The parameter is for enabling translations

Comment: Thanks. I'll try disabling it some other way.